# Differentiating a inverse trig function in various intervals

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, inverse-function

I have a question that says:

Differentiate $\sin^{-1}(4x\sqrt{1-4x^2})$ with respect to $\sqrt{1-4x^2}$, if

(i) $x \in \bigg(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt2},\frac{1}{2\sqrt2} \bigg)$
(ii) $x \in \bigg(\frac{1}{2\sqrt2},\frac{1}{2} \bigg)$
(iii) $x \in \bigg(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2\sqrt2} \bigg)$

The answers of the set of questions is: (i)$-\frac{1}{x}$ (ii)$\frac{1}{x}$ (iii)$\frac{1}{x}$

I am not sure how the different intervals are supposed to affect my question.
Here's what I tried:

I substituted $2x = \cos \theta$, so y $= \sin^{-1}(4x\sqrt{1-4x^2}) = \sin^{-1}(sin 2\theta)$

I know that $\sin^{-1}(sin 2\theta) = 2\theta$ for $2\theta \in \bigg[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg]$

So, $\frac{dy}{d\theta} = 2$

and z = $\sqrt{1-4x^2} = \sin \theta$, so I get $\frac{dz}{d \theta} = \cos \theta$

So, I get from here that $\frac{dy}{dz}=\frac{1}{x}$, while the answer says $\frac{-1}{x}$
However, if I had subbed $2x = \sin \theta$, then I would have got the correct answer for this part.

I dont know what I'm supposed to do with the interval of $x$, like, I know that $x \in \bigg(-\frac{1}{2\sqrt2},\frac{1}{2\sqrt2} \bigg)$ so $\cos \theta \in \bigg[\frac{-1}{\sqrt2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\bigg]$, but where does that get me?

Comment: I've actually survived the equivalent of a 1 year Real Analysis course, and I was baffled by your problem.  There is one aspect that I think that **may** (or **may not**, I am just guessing) be helpful.  Suppose that $x < 0$ and you are asked to evaluate $\sqrt{x^2}$.  The answer will be $(-x)$.

Comment: @user2661923 I've actually found the answer just now, with the help of a hint from the answer below. Should I be posting it? Then I'll post it when I get the time, can't really format on mobile right now.

Comment: If your answer varies significantly from the posted answer, or your answer will include details that you regard as significant that are missing from the posted answer, then I would say **yes** post your answer; otherwise **no** there is no reason to.  If you are going to post your answer, then you might just as well add an **Addendum** section to your query and post it there.  Alternatively, if your answer is lengthy, and the interface allows you to post as a separate answer, then I would add an addendum to your query indicating that you have posted an answer, then post your answer separately

Comment: Then I'll probably select the answer below as the correct one. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Using [principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values), WLOG  $0\le\theta\le\pi\iff0\le2\theta\le2\pi$

and as $\cos\theta$ is decreasing in $\left[0,\pi\right]$

$$\sin^{-1}(\sin2\theta)= \begin{cases}2\theta &\mbox{if } 0\le2\theta\le\dfrac\pi2\iff\cos0\ge \cos\theta\ge\cos\dfrac\pi4\\
\pi-2\theta & \mbox{if } 0\le\pi-2\theta\le\dfrac\pi2\iff\dfrac\pi2\le2\theta\le\pi\\
-2\pi+2\theta & \mbox{if } 0\le-2\pi+2\theta\le\dfrac\pi2\iff\pi\le2\theta\le2\pi+\dfrac\pi2 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Ive tried this many times. I know that cos in decreasing in that interval. I got the range of cos as I have denoted at the end of the question, but when I take cos inverse of that, am I supposed to reverse the inequality?

Comment: But isn't the range of theta from -π/4 to π/4? Why do you consider it from 0?

Comment: @Techie5879, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Comment: I was baffled by both the OP's work and your answer - I have survived Vol 1 of Apostol's "Calculus 2nd Ed".  My approach, given the instructions was : (1) Let $u = \sqrt{1 - 4x^2}.$  (2) Convert $4x\sqrt{1-4x^2}$ into $f(u).$ (3) Compute $\frac{d}{du} [\text{Arcsin} f(u)].$  (4) Convert the answer back into an expression in $x$.  I understand that (for example) if $t<0$, then $\sqrt{t^2} = (-t).$  Other than that consideration, I got the right answer.: [A] Do you consider my approach valid? [B] Is there an online reference (or free pdf) that explains your approach, which is foreign to me?